# Xquery returning string instead of formatted date

Tags: xml, date, datetime, xquery, documentum

I am running a simple Xquery on an XML repository, Xhive, and am having trouble with the value being returned for a date:

Xquery:

```
for $x in document('')[matches(xhive:metadata(., "docato-name"),"THOCEO")][xhive:metadata(., "docato-type") = 'XML_RESOURCE_TYPE']
return
<file>
      <filename>{xhive:metadata($x, "docato-name")}</filename>
      <validated>{xhive:metadata($x,"Last Modified")}</validated>
</file>
```

Result:

```
<result>
    <file>
        <filename>THOCEO</filename>
        <validated>1375875821721</validated>
    </file>
</result>
```

I would like the "Last Modified" date returned as a formatted date as it appears in the repository: "2013-08-07 12:43:41" not as a string as above ("1375875821721")

I have tried amending the query to "{xs:date(xhive:metadata($x,"Last Modified"))}" but this fails with error:

```
query:8:19:XQUERY_ERROR_VALUE: casting error, cannot cast '1375875821721' from xdt:untypedAtomic to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date (FORG0001: Invalid value for cast/constructor.)
```

Any help to return the "Last modified" date as  a formated date would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I would say using xhive:last-modified(...) is the easiest way, but if you really want to use the timestamp then here is something that I've used in the past:

```
declare function local:timestamp-to-dateTime($v) as xs:dateTime { 
  xs:dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00-00:00") + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat("PT", $v idiv 1000, "S"))
};

local:timestamp-to-dateTime(number("1375875821721"))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that Ewout, does the trick!I'm afraid i cant give you a +1 cause of my puny reputation of 1, but will try and remember to if i ever get to 15!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what that number represents or how to parse it, but you could try `xhive:last-modified()` instead, which returns `xs:dateTime`:

```
<validated>{ xhive:last-modified(fn:document-uri($x)) }</validated>
```

Comment: Hi, when i try to run the xhive:last-modified function you detail above i get the following error: `query:8:20:XQUERY_UNKNOWN_FUNCTION: {http://www.x-hive.com/2001/08/xquery-functions}last-modified/1 (XPST0017: It is a static error if the expanded QName and number of arguments in a function call do not match the name and arity of a function signature in the static context.)`

Comment: @user2083508 Are you sure you're not passing empty to the function? Can you isolate a single call to `xhive:last-modified()`?